# youtube-upload [Errno 54] Connection reset by peer

Tags: python, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm currently facing this problem when batch uploading video by youtube-upload .sh.  What can i do to prevent this?  Can anyone teach me how I can write something in .sh to take action on this error?  Should I retry the last row of the script or something else?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/bin/youtube-upload", line 5, in <module>
    main.run()
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/youtube_upload/main.py", line 214, in run
    sys.exit(lib.catch_exceptions(EXIT_CODES, main, sys.argv[1:]))
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/youtube_upload/lib.py", line 35, in catch_exceptions
    fun(*args, **kwargs)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/youtube_upload/main.py", line 211, in main
    run_main(parser, options, args)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/youtube_upload/main.py", line 153, in run_main
    video_id = upload_youtube_video(youtube, options, video_path, len(args), index)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/youtube_upload/main.py", line 121, in upload_youtube_video
    request_body, progress_callback=progress.callback)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/youtube_upload/upload_video.py", line 37, in upload
    RETRIABLE_EXCEPTIONS, max_retries=max_retries)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/youtube_upload/lib.py", line 71, in retriable_exceptions
    raise exc
socket.error: [Errno 54] Connection reset by peer`
```

This is what i'm using in .sh file, i've repeat 20 rows for different video.

```
youtube-upload --title="" --client-secrets=client_secrets.json -- description="" --tags="" --thumbnail="" --playlist="" --privacy="unlisted" /users/desktop/video/4.mp4
```

Comment: You probably need [authentication](https://github.com/tokland/youtube-upload#authentication).

Comment: @user880772 Thanks for your help, but Client_secrets.json isn't authentication? I only fail to upload 3 to 4 videos in 20 videos. I've done the authentication. Any authentication else?

Comment: Maybe your video is [too large](https://code.google.com/p/youtube-upload/issues/detail?id=56)?

Comment: @user880772 nope, not even 100 mb.